# AlarmManager alarm goes off immediately and ignores delay

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I'm trying to do a simple Alarm manager, and although I'm adding a delay of 5 second, 
the alarm in my phone goes off immediately.

I'm aware that in my receiver the alarm says to go off now, 
but I understood that you set the delay to when you want it to go off at the pending intent.

what am I doing wrong ?

here is my alarm intent:

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent (AlarmClockScreen.this, AlarmNotificationReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+5000,pendingIntent);
```

and here is my Receiver

```
public class AlarmNotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm TITLE")
                .setContentText("I will finish, What you started")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
and then using time.getTimeInMillis()
```